# How does carrier size / bandwidth effect propagation

Tags: ofdm, bandwidth

I'm working with software-defined coded orthogonal frequency division multiplexing radios.
They have a choice of bandwidth, 1,2,3-20MHz.

Of course, as you increase your bandwidth (carrier size), you increase your throughput. However, is there an equation or rule of thumb that indicates if 20MHz gets you x-distance, 10MHz will get you y-distance?

Thanks
Gabriel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no such equation. In general, why would the system bandwidth in a multi-carrier system affect reach? The subcarriers are still the same width, just a different number of them, and they are equalized *individually*; that's the whole point of doing OFDM instead of a single-carrier transmission.

If, in the sense of fairness, you fix the *total* transmission power, of course (assuming white noise), you'd be lowering the SNR inversely proportional to the number of subcarriers – but if you also keep the data rate constant, you can now spend more subcarriers for the same amount of bits, and your $E_b/N_0$ again stays unchanged.

Comment: If I have a SDR radio. Such as [Domo Transmitter](https://www.domotactical.com/products/solo7-hdntx-high-definition-nano-transmitter-compact-hd-av-transmitter) and it boasts 8000 subcarriers at a 8MHz bandwidth. If I reduce the bandwidth to 4MHz and the number of subcarriers reduce to 4000, my SNR would improve?

Comment: if it's SDR, then why would it define the subcarriers? That's up to your software to do. No, reducing the subcarriers at a fixed bandwidth would not increase SNR, it would just make equalization worse. I'll be honest, I think the most productive thing for you to do is read up on basics of OFDM :)

Comment: I have done some reading! I understand my initial foolishness (still a fair way to go). Suppose I have a DVB-T modulation with 8000 subcarriers. If I reduce my bandwidth from 8MHz to 6MHz, do the size of the subcarriers scale (1.17KHz to 0.8KHz)? Does it increase SNR proportionally?

Comment: You can either reduce the bandwidth of an OFDM system by reducing the subcarrier count, or by reducing the subcarrier spacing. What you do depends on *why* you want to reduce the bandwidth – that's exactly what we're discussing in this answer: Keep the spacing the same, and you get the same equalization abilities, but shorter symbols and hence, better ability to work with time-varying channels. Keep the symbol duration the same and reduce the subcarrier spacing: you get better equalization of a frequency-selective channel, but unchanged ability to work with a time-varying channel.